# INDEX + MATCH to return the greatest of all matching values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, vlookup, google-sheets-dates

I'm looking for the *most recent* date corresponding to a particular name. Dates are not necessarily ordered. I can't sort the target, I need it to work in any order.

```
Example: When was [Roberto]'s most recent haircut?
input:  "Roberto" 
desired output: "4/6"
```

---

```
Name     Date of haircut
Roberto  1/21
Xi       1/22
Jess     1/31
Roberto  4/6
Barbara  3/1
Mary     2/2
Roberto  3/10
```

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXT(VLOOKUP(A2, QUERY(A:B, "order by A, B desc"), 2, 0), "m/d")
```

[image: 0]